# Create selinux context for systemd script?

Tags: redhat, systemd, fedora, selinux, rhel8

I'm trying to create a systemd service that executes a custom script I wrote.  It is just a backup script that I am using with a systemd timer.  When I try to execute something simple in the systemd file like "/usr/bin/free" or something like that, it works perfectly.  However when I try to execute my script "/root/scripts/mybackupscript.sh", it fails with:

`Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC`

If I set selinux to permissive, it will start my script with no problem.

So I know that selinux is restricting systemd from executing my script.  But I don't know how to use selinux.  How do I create an selinux context to allow systemd to execute my script?

Example:
This systemd file runs no problem:

```
[Unit]
Description=Logs system statistics to the systemd journal
Wants=myMonitor.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/free

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But this script fails (unless if I set selinux to permissive, in which case it executes fine):

```
[Unit]
Description=Logs system statistics to the systemd journal
Wants=myMonitor.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/scripts/mybackupscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your script out of the user's home directory. SELinux rightly complains about trying to execute system services located in users' home directories.

Use a more standard location, such as `/usr/local/bin`:

```
install -m755 /root/scripts/mybackupscript.sh /usr/local/bin
```

And of course edit the unit file to match.

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mybackupscript.sh
```

Comment: Of course!  Thank you, this solved the issue.